# Esper: Take the last value from each id and take the mean of all but the most extreme

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I have 5 temperature sensors. I want to calculate the mean temperature of 4 - excluding the most extreme value (high or low).

Firstly: will std:unique(id) create a window of the last temperature readings for each id 1-5?

```
select
    avg(tempEvent.temp) as meantemp
from
    Event(id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).std:unique(id) as tempEvent
```

Secondly: how could I change the select statement (possibly using an expression if necessary) to only calculate the mean of four values excluding the most extreme?

The background is, I want to know the deviations of each temperature from the average, but I don't want the average to include an anomalous id. Otherwise all temperatures will look like they are deviating from the average but really only one is.

Comment: If this is an Esper questions make sure to remove "SQL" and "Influxdb" tags

Comment: You could use an inlined_class and pass "window(temp)" to a Java method. Or use EPL enumeration methods i.e. "window(temp).average(v => ...)"

Answer (score 1):

Finding the average of the middle four values is simple enough, though not as elegant as your solution. The code below will work for any number of temps.

```
SELECT
   AVG(temp) AS meantemp
FROM (
     SELECT
        temp,
        COUNT(temp) AS c,
        RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY temp ORDER BY temp) AS r
     FROM
        [table]
     )
 WHERE
     r > 1
     AND r < (c-1)
 ;
```

As for your second question, I'm not sure I understand. Do you want the value from among the four middle values that has the greatest absolute deviation from the mean *of those four values*?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my question. The other question is, how do I get the mean of only the last values from each id. Also could you explain how your code works? I.e. I am not familiar with partition or rank () over. Also is [table] a keyword or is it the event object?

Comment: This solution is not EPL however, its SQL and not streaming